# UICollectionView refreshing with a new set of data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am trying to delete the entire contents of the collectionView using the following function after reading the apple documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH7-SW7

It ends up with the following error.

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the collection view after the update (0) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the collection view before the update (5), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'**

What does this mean? Or can anyone  show me a reference link with an  example of how to refresh the contents of collectionView with a new set of data on clicking a button.

```
-(void) clearCollectionViewAndDataArray
{

[self.galleryCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [displayDataArray removeAllObjects];
    NSLog(@"Is it empty---?%@",displayDataArray);
  [self.galleryCollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[self createIndexPathArrayEntireCollectionView]];
}
completion:nil ];
}




-(NSMutableArray*) createIndexPathArrayEntireCollectionView
{

NSMutableArray* indexPathArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i=0; i < [displayDataArray count]; i++)
{

    NSMutableArray* sectionArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    sectionArray=[displayDataArray objectAtIndex:i];
    for(int j=0; j < [sectionArray count]; j++)
    {
        NSIndexPath* newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:i];
        [indexPathArray addObject: newPath];
    }

}

return indexPathArray;

}
```

The NSMutableArray data used is:

```
(
(
"<SACatalogs: 0x9554750>",
    "<SACatalogs: 0x953d9c0>",
    "<SACatalogs: 0x953e050>"
),
    (
    "<SACatalogs: 0x953e6e0>",
    "<SACatalogs: 0x953ed70>",
    "<SACatalogs: 0x953f420>"
),
    (
    "<SACatalogs: 0x953fab0>",
    "<SACatalogs: 0x9540160>",
    "<SACatalogs: 0x95407f0>"
),
    (
    "<SACatalogs: 0x9540ec0>",
    "<SACatalogs: 0x9541530>",
    "<SACatalogs: 0x9541be0>"
),
    (
    "<SACatalogs: 0x9542290>",
    "<SACatalogs: 0x9542940>",
    "<SACatalogs: 0x9542ff0>"
)
)
```

The index path used is

```
"<NSIndexPath 0xa6bb9a0> 2 indexes [0, 0]",
"<NSIndexPath 0xa648bc0> 2 indexes [0, 1]",
"<NSIndexPath 0xa6dcdc0> 2 indexes [0, 2]",
"<NSIndexPath 0xa6c7d00> 2 indexes [1, 0]",
"<NSIndexPath 0xa6c91c0> 2 indexes [1, 1]",
"<NSIndexPath 0xa6f6100> 2 indexes [1, 2]",
"<NSIndexPath 0xa6490d0> 2 indexes [2, 0]",
"<NSIndexPath 0xa6a93b0> 2 indexes [2, 1]",
"<NSIndexPath 0xa6d08b0> 2 indexes [2, 2]",
"<NSIndexPath 0xa64ddb0> 2 indexes [3, 0]",
"<NSIndexPath 0xa6f7380> 2 indexes [3, 1]",
"<NSIndexPath 0xa6c1c90> 2 indexes [3, 2]",
"<NSIndexPath 0xa6e45f0> 2 indexes [4, 0]",
"<NSIndexPath 0xa6bf840> 2 indexes [4, 1]",
"<NSIndexPath 0xa6a03f0> 2 indexes [4, 2]"
```

}

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you are trying to just all the content just remove all the data from your array and call [collectionView reloadData].

Comment: @Pete42 Yes, i had tried it. And it is succesful when there is no data. It ends up with error EXC_BAD_ACCESS when i update the array with new data. And i feel it is something related to Array allocation...:-(

Comment: You have to make sure that the number of sections and number of items for your delegate methods match the contents you are trying to access in your array. If your collection view's item at index function tries to access something out of range in your array it will give EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you remove all objects from `displayDataArray` first, and then compute the
`indexPathArray` from `displayDataArray`. Therefore `indexPathArray` will be empty
and

```
[self.galleryCollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[self createIndexPathArrayEntireCollectionView]];
```

does *nothing*. Changing the order to

```
[self.galleryCollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[self createIndexPathArrayEntireCollectionView]];
[displayDataArray removeAllObjects];
```

could solve the problem. But as mentioned in a comment, you can just call 
`reloadData` if *all* collection view items have been removed.

Comment: i have tried but no way, the link in the apple documentation shown above  also refers the method of changing the display array and then do the delete operation. I couldnt find a program sample which updates the collectionView on click of a button...:-(

Comment: @VARUNISAC: Within a performBatchUpdates block, it does not matter if you change the data source or delete the collection view items first. And note that in your code, displayDataArray is already *empty* when createIndexPathArrayEntireCollectionView is called.

Comment: I cant figure out the problem, but i by found that the problem occurs when the data source is empty, I bypassed the error by adding an empty invisible cell !!!